# Show that a space is complete metric space for continuous functions with given norm.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X = \{ f \in C(\mathbb{R}) \, \colon \, ||f|| \leq 100 \}$

where given number $100$ is arbitrary (some got $200$, some $40000$; all positive numbers).

Needed to show that $X$ is complete metric space.

Continuous functions space $C$ is linear normed real (or complex) space.
The definition says that a space is a complete metric space if every Cauchy sequence converges into $X$ ( so does not exceed $100$ in this case).  How do I go about these Cauchy sequences?

For space $C$ it says that $||f||≥0$. Does this fact helps anything, and how does that upper limit of $100$ changes anything?? Have never done anything like this and feel totally out of the water.

I am so confused about this. Thanks for any advice! :]

Comment: Assuming the norm is the supremum norm, $X$ is the continuous preimage of a closed set in the Banach space of bounded continuous functions...

Answer (score 0):

I assume that $||f|| := \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |f(x)|$. The specific number ($100, 1000$) won't change much in the argument. First, try to understand what the norm $||\cdot||$ implies regarding converging sequences in $X$. A sequence $f_n \in X$ converges to an element $f \in X$ if and only if

$$ ||f_n - f|| = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |f_n(x) - f(x)| \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} 0 $$

which happens if and only if $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Given a Cauchy sequence $f_n$ of elements of $X$, we have

$$ |f_n(x) - f_m(x)| \leq ||f_n - f_m|| $$

which implies that each $f_n(x)$ (for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$) is a Cauchy sequence of real numbers, and hence converges to a limit which we will call $f(x)$. Since $|f_n(x)| \leq 100$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we must have $|f(x)| \leq 100$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

To finish, show that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ (and hence, $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $X$) and that $f \in X$ (so $f$ is continuous and $||f|| \leq 100$).